# Did I really mess up my repository with my messing around?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

a bit of a git newcomer and I wanted to make sure I didn't do any big damage to my git repository. Basically, I used `git reset --hard HEAD` to revert back to my previous commit as I messed some things up. I then realized I didn't want to lose everything I had done, so I did a `git reset HEAD@{1}`. Which didn't seem to do anything helpful. Then I tried a `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`.

So I figured, whatever, I'll do the little bit of work over. After I did, I went to push it, and I kept getting this error:

> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

I tried `git pull origin` and it kept not allowing it for a bunch of reasons I can't totally remember.

In the end, I just ended up doing a `git push -f` and it seemed to work fine and my project is working well again.

Here's my `git reflog` output if it helps:

[image]

I'm just curious if I somehow really messed up either my BitBucket repository that I pushed to or my local one in terms of being able to revert back again. Is there any way to check if my git repo is still functioning properly?

EDIT: BitBucket also says I "stripped" a commit...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## It's going to be ok

Relax.

To ease your concerns, clone another copy in a different directory. Then check things out and bring in the new code you want to push. It will all work out.

## Ack! A commit is dangling!

Based on your text I think you might have re-written master's commit history/tree, as a result of `git reset HEAD@{1}` followed by `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`. Running through exactly what you said, I too "lost" one commit.

This was likely the error message you saw.

```
20:19:44 (master) ~/code/wat/so_test$ git push
To git@github.com:rgbkrk/so_test.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:rgbkrk/so_test.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Forcing the git push caused the master branch to take your new path.

Remember how I said to relax? Well, that commit hasn't disappeared. Provided you have the original repo you were working in, it should still be in the `git reflog`, but not in `git log`. It's just out there dangling.

```
2b47149 HEAD@{2}: commit: The bad commit
01346b9 HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to ORIG_HEAD
42af608 HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to HEAD@{3}
01346b9 HEAD@{5}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
2f2d2ce HEAD@{6}: commit: More junk text
01346b9 HEAD@{7}: commit: Text
42af608 HEAD@{8}: clone: from git@github.com:rgbkrk/so_test.git
```

If you truly need that commit back you can do a diff on that commit and the HEAD of your current master. `git diff 2f2d2ce..HEAD` in the case of the repo I created for this question. You can always merge it into master too.

An easy way to find the "unreachable" commits is to use `git fsck`, making sure to enable `--no-reflogs`.

```
20:48:02 (master) ~/code/wat/so_test$ git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
unreachable tree 0ca2f12b74de7a33f6dc62374a85d982a96531ce
unreachable commit 2f2d2ce1b6591f0e7a5f67af81a125231ee2e9a1
unreachable blob bcb7bae71bbdfb79ba31ee41e4aa3a11b1ad2f7f
```

For more on restoring lost commits, check out [git ready's article](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html).

## Notes for the Future

Couple things to point out: `git reset --hard` can be dangerous since it throws away all your uncommitted changes. If you have some work you want to keep, but don't want it in this commit, use [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing).

Comment: Well, my BitBucket repo does have the latest code I want to push, and when I clone it down I can seemingly `git reset` to any point back that I want, so I should seemingly be good, right?

Comment: For now, yes. The only concern I have is that you might have done a force push when actually a commit or two behind master.

Comment: Thanks for all that information, it really cleared it up. So basically, unless I need that one small commit don't worry?

Comment: Yeah, if it really is just one commit. I'd compare the hashes from your `git reflog` to your `git log` just in case so you at least know where master diverges.

Comment: Oh! I should point out that BitBucket's message about a stripped commit is that they have reference to a commit that isn't part of a tree (you've stripped that branch). The message will go away eventually.

Comment: After running `git fsck` I see that I have a crap ton of dangling blobs (but only one commit) is that normal?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40429/discussion-between-kyle-kelley-and-doug-smith)